# Adding song to iTunes Playlist stuck on "in progress" or error 11.444

Tags: itunes, apple-music, playlist

So, I'm trying to make a playlist for a party this weekend, and it's horrible. iTunes more often than not shows "in progress" when adding one single song (this shouldn't take longer than 1 second, I recon) and finally, it will just show a `!` with "Due to error 11.444".

I can't find anything about this error, and I have quite some songs left to add, so I'm hoping to find a solution here.

Edit: The same seems to sometimes happen whenever I restart iTunes after I can't successfully add a song, but then with "Making your iCloud music library available"

Edit 2: Sometimes it also goes as expected for at least a few songs, only to result in the same "processing" and then `!` again.

Here are some screenshots, where I tried to add 2 whole songs to the playlist:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Heb jij al een oplossing gevonden? Ik heb precies hetzelfde probleem en kom er ook niet uit. Fijne zondag en hartelijke groet, Dees

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. I translated your _answer_ and found this isn't actually an answer, but a comment. Please don't add comments in the _Answer_ field as this is for answers to questions. Once you have enough [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you can add a comment on the question/answer you wanted to comment on. Alternatively, if you have an answer instead, see [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.